# Code blockquotes on beta sites add extra spacing to bottom

Tags: bug, markdown, beta-sites, code-block, blockquote

Currently, when you try to format blocks of code inside a blockquote, you get extra spacing at the bottom of the blockquote. Here are a couple of examples:

> [image]
>
> [image]

While this isn't a huge deal, it still looks odd, and it would be nice if it could be fixed.

Comment: Yeah, reproduced.

Comment: I see it on all sites, not just beta sites.